# Column letter(s) based on value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I download a sheet every two weeks where I use a formula to calculate specific expenses. The names of the people and their location in the sheet are always the same and the categories (based on which I need to calculate) are also similar. But they do change and as a result I need to manually change my formula all the time. 
Let me explain this to make it more clear:

On line 5 of the Excel sheet there are 50 categories like "Taxes - EE-Federal Withholding", "Taxes-Total", etc, etc.

I have a formula that calculates totals based on departments. I know rows 6-8 are department 1, 9-18 are department 2 and so on. My formula is like below, but since the categories always change columns, I need to find the column and then change the number in the formula.

Example: `=SUM(BG6:BG7)+SUM(AW6:AW7)` (sometimes it is BG, sometimes BH or AX, etc)

What I would love to have is to have a formula based on the value in row 5. 
These categories have the same name 100% of the time.

I know that `=SUM(BG6:BG7)+SUM(AW6:AW7)`
really is: `=SUM(Workers Comp Fee Total, row 6:7) + Employer Paid Benefits Total, row 6:7)`

Is there a way to find the column letter based on a specific value? So if it says "Workers Comp Fee Total" in line 5, tell me the column letter or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MATCH` function to find which column has a certain header. Then you can use the `INDEX` function to return the range that includes rows 6 and 7 of that column. Finally you can use the `SUM` function to add up the values in that range.

In the following example, the headers are in range AV5:AZ5 and the data is in range AV6:AZ8. To get the sum of the values in rows 6 and 7 of the columns headed "Workers Comp Fee Total" and "Employer Paid Benefits Total", use the following formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX($AV$6:$AZ$7,0,MATCH("Workers Comp Fee Total",$AV$5:$AZ$5,0)))+SUM(INDEX($AV$6:$AZ$7,0,MATCH("Employer Paid Benefits Total",$AV$5:$AZ$5,0)))
```

[image]